# Is it possible to create something like this using Flutter ? #DesignChallenge

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, flutter-layout

I was wondering If someone could help me design something like this using Flutter :

[image: Design]

So far, I've tried creating two containers on top of each other but I do not know how to make that semi circle in the middle of the card.

Also, It would be great If we could cut this image into two equal halves and write code for both of them separately. The reason being, I need to put data into the two halves and I want the height to be dynamic (not fixed).

I want to create this using the best design approach. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it :

1. Create a Column as the parent with two children.
2. Create container as the first child.
3. Create a stack as the second child.

Now, since we have stack as the second child, we can have three children in it.

1. First child being the left circle/semi circle positioned at left:0 and top:0.
2. Second child being the right circle/semi circle positioned at right:0 and top:0
3. Third child being a container with no positional constraints. Put left:0 and right:0 to stretch it all the way and fit the screen.

This would give us the required results without having to use any other complicated way.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CustomPaint`, read more [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html), and [fluttershapemaker](https://fluttershapemaker.com) can help you do it easily by drawing it or converting this SVG to `CustomPaint` code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of ways you can do that

1. Instead of making a circe container you can use a normal rectangle container and give topRight and bottomRight high borderRadius on the left side and on the right side you would give the container high border radius on topLeft and bottomLeft. the code will look something like

```dart
Container(height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,aligment:Alignment.center, child:Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
      Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(100),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(100),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(100),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ]),),
```

2. If you want to stick with creating a circle you can add to circles on a stack and position them on a negative value of left and right. resulting in cutting the circle how ever you want.

I hope this helps